# Wordpress Ixion Theme - Featured Content Launch

Tags: javascript, wordpress

There is wordpress theme called Ixion

It has a feature called Featured Content

[image: what it should look like]

When I downloaded theme, it don't show any featured posts, even when I added featured images to three posts.

I need to display three featured PAGES not posts.

My question is how to make this feature - Featured content be visible and how to switch displaying pages instead of posts.

[image: feature template]

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://wordpress.com/theme/ixion) of the theme? There are instructions in there explaining how to set up the Featured Content area.

Comment: Yes but I dont see the Feautred Content in Customize opotions. what should I do to make it visible

Comment: No idea. If the Featured Content panel is missing from the Customizer then your best bet is to [reach out to the theme developer and ask them directly about this](https://wordpress.org/support/theme/ixion/).

Answer (score 0):

Downloading Jetpack plugin resolves the problem.